# Java Runtime not Work EXP Oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, runtime.exec

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("EXP MASTER/MASTER@localhost FILE=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\BKP.DMP STATISTICS=NONE");

        int processComplete = p.waitFor();
        if (processComplete==0) {
            jLabel1.setText("Backup Ok");
        }else{
            jLabel1.setText("Backup not Ok");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I used this code, but EXP in task manager not exit this code export the dmp file but not done, the program locking

Comment: With Exp Path not work, the EXPDP not work too i not got

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.